# Inbuilt browser preview extension in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any extension in Visual Studio code which allows me to view the html file in built VS code browser which has seperate view for multiple responsive widths like shown in the below image. On the right side of the image you can find sm, md, lg and xl browser preview. Is there any such extension?

[image]

Comment: most of the extensions do not have this responsive widths inbuilt to the browser. I need the one which has responsive widths option inbuilt to the browser

Comment: are you sure it is VSC shown in the video, if you can't find it why not write it yourself